# Replace without proceeding to the next find in Word via VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

Does anyone know if it is possible to do a replace function within Word via VB.Net without the automatic move to the next 'hit'? It seems that the replace function is actually a replace/find.

I am now thinking of doing a search, place a bookmark, execute a replace and then move the focus back to the bookmark. That in itself is not that hard, but is seems not very efficient.

There is no code yet, since I am still investigating the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be of some use to you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1558f560-8ae6-413a-bbc4-aa8d5d912aac/find-replace-in-a-word-document-by-vbnet

```
'credit to martin xie
Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Trydata\1.doc")   
    objDoc = objWordApp.ActiveDocument   

    'Find and replace some text   
    'Replace 'VB' with 'Visual Basic'   
    objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="VB", ReplaceWith:="Visual Basic Express", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)   
    While objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)   
        objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", ReplaceWith:=" ", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)   
    End While
```

Otherwise, not sure what your intent is.  Why do you want to find/replace and then move back to the bookmark?  What is your goal and why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I do know how to do a normal search/replace in Word via VB.Net, but thanks for the try. The goal is to test out a regex/wildcard search and replace. For a good test, you need to see the actual replacement instead of the next find.

Comment: @Toxaris then why dont you output the document and look at the replacements? Otherwise, a better way may be to interpret the document as an XML file and parse that way.

Comment: Actually because those would not be visible. It is meant as a helpful tool for people to create/test more complex S&R actions.

Comment: Why would your document replacements not be visible? In order to test your S&R logic, wouldnt you create dummy text, do the S&R and look at the file afterwards to make sure your S&R occured?

Comment: I would, but not the users using this. They would testdrive on the real document... I think I will skip the option though.